# What is the proper way to check if a Boolean key exists in NSUserdefaults/UserDefaults

Tags: swift, boolean, nsuserdefaults

Which of the two examples below is best for checking if a `boolean` key exists in `NSUserdefaults`?

**1- Is this acceptable?**

```
if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("myKey"){
   print("Key Does Exist")
}
```

**2- Is this the preferred way?**

```
if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("myKey") != nil) {
     print("Key Does Exist")
}
```

Comment: (1) and (2) are different. The first condition is true if a boolean value for the key exists *and* the value is `true`. See documentation: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults/1416388-bool.

Comment: Why won't you register defaults by `NSUserDefaults.registerDefaults `?

Comment: @MartinR - I see. Is the second acceptable for checking if a key exists, regardless of what type the value is?

Comment: @Szu - I always use `registerDefaults` in `AppDelegate` for values that I need to exist for sure but I need to understand how to check if a key exists for keys that may never need to be set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to verify if something is stored for a key, the second option is fine (Swift 3).

```
if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().object(forKey: "myKey") != nil) {
     print("Key Does Exist")
}
```

`object(forKey:)` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults/1410095-object) mentions that `nil` is returned if the key is not found.

---

But if you want to verify if something is stored for a key, and it's actually a `Boolean`: neither versions are fine.

- First [verifies](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults/1416388-bool) if the `Boolean` value exists and actually is `true`.
- The second verifies if an object exists, but you can't be sure it's a `Boolean`.

Check the following possibility (Swift 3):

```
if let boolValue = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().object(forKey: "myKey"), 
  boolValue is Bool {
  // Boolean exists
}
```

Comment: I only want to know if a key exists or not, not about its value. Thanks

Comment: @ Dimitri Pavlutin - Just to clarify something, the second example is fine for checking if a key exists regardless of its value, correct?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification and for the other example. Quick question, on your Swift 3 suggestion I would change `is Bool` for `is Double` if I would want to check for a double?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if a value exists you will use the second method.
The first method you are just checking the value if its true or false
First method is the same is doing

```
    let booleanValue = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("myKey")
    if booleanValue{

    }
```

However the second method checks for the value
A nice way to do what you are trying to do is

```
if let booleanValue = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("myKey"){
    print(booleanValue)         
}
```

this will allow you to get access to the boolean and it gives you the boolean as a variable that you can play with